# Local root server: IXFR & TSIG

Tags: domain-name-system

I found those slides https://www.isc.org/docs/Apricot2017.pdf that replied to my question if root servers allow or not IXFR. But I do not get why IXFR is not allowed on root servers?

Also, without TSIG, how to ensure the authenticity and integrity of the messages when running a local root server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### IXFR of the root zone

I think that the lack of IXFR is not necessarily purely a policy thing (as implied by "allowed" in the question), but rather a technical limitation based on that the root servers likely do not maintain/have the version history of the zone data, which is a requirement to be able to construct IXFR responses.
Also, I imagine that constructing IXFR responses comes with rather resource-intensive worst-case scenarios, which could open up for abuse of a non-essential feature available in absolutely critical infrastructure.

In that respect, I would have found it more likely if the dedicated [ICANN zone transfer service](https://www.dns.icann.org/services/axfr/) would have allowed IXFR, but to my understanding it also does not.

#### Zone data authenticity

For the matter of data authentication, you are right that a plain AXFR (or IXFR) without TSIG could trivially be tampered with by a man in the middle.
This is definitely an important thing to consider, but the data authentication situation is very similar to your regular queries to the root servers.
Looking in the document that you reference, they prescribe the exact same solution as for regular queries: DNSSEC.

This is why the document you referenced says to set up either two views (BIND specific and maybe more complexity than it is worth) or two nameserver instances (could be either BIND or something else):

1. One view/server which is authoritative for the root zone (slave)
2. One view/server which provides recursion to clients and has a static-stub root zone using server/view 1.

The whole purpose of that somewhat convoluted exercise is to force the recursive service to validate DNSSEC even though the root zone is hosted locally, specifically because the data is not seen as inherently trusted.

#### Other options

The root zone is available in [master file format over https](https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone) from Internic/ICANN. This is a little inconvenient in terms of integration, but could certainly be usable.

AXFR over TLS (DoT) could also be an option (provided a trusted source), but I do not believe this is in place for the root zone.